# How to get first stack frame outside this file

Tags: python, path, stack-trace

I'm writing some custom logging code in python. I'd like to find out the line number and filename of the function that called my logging function, while ignoring any calls from within the current module.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
def _make_line_log_message(self, level, message):
    stack = inspect.stack()
    for frame_record in stack:
        frame, filename, line, function, src_context, src_context_line = frame_record
        if filename == __file__:  # This doesn't work
            continue

        do_my_logging(filename, line, message)
        break
```

But the filename from `inspect.stack()` uses the full path of the file, while `__file__` is just the filename without the path. How can I get the filename of the current file so that it would match `inspect.stack()`? Will `os.path.realpath(__file__)` always exactly match the filename format of `inspect.stack()` or is there a better way?